# NSURLConnectionLoader exception with OS X but working with IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, security, nsurlconnection

I'm using the same Xcode project to build the same App on IOS and OSX. I'm new as OSX developer.

For this Application I'm sharing code to send HTTPS request to a server using NSURLConnection. It works perfectly well with IOS but with OSX I have some troubles.

In OSX, when the request is sent I have an exception in NSURLConnectionLoader (see screenshot) that never happen in IOS. In Xcode if I click many times "Continue" on the debugger the request is sent and I'm receiving correctly the response from the server.

Once the first request has been sent the following requests are sent without error! I have no idea how to progress on this issue.

Any idea is welcomed! I was wondering if it could be due to issue with entitlement and/or conflict with IOS App because it's managed in the same Xcode project.
Regards,

Sébastien.[image]

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 6):

This can happen on OSX if you have an All Exceptions Breakpoint set for the project. For some reason any HTTPS address will throw an internal exception that will cause this. If you remove the breakpoint it should resolve your issue.

Comment: How are you supposed to catch exceptions in the debugger then?

Answer (score 0):

If you run rather than debug, does it just work?

Comment: When I run it in Xcode it stops with the exception in the screenshot. Next if I click many times on "Continue" it sends the request to the Server and I'm receiving the answer as expected.

Comment: I have created and archive and exported it as an Application and it seems it's working correctly. Is it an issue with Xcode?